# Pandas: find maximum value across all columns and print this row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a large dataframe with normalised and scaled data which should be in a range 0-1. But when I print its maximum values I get - 1.000000002. `describe()` method doesn't show this value. So I'm trying to identify the problem and want to print a row in question. All other answers I got across are talking about printing a row with a maximum value of a certain column. How can I print a row which contains a maximum value for the whole dataframe? Will appreciate your help!

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'att1'  : [0.1, 0.001, 0.0001,
                            1, 2,
                            0.5, 0, -1, -2],
                   'att2':[0.01, 0.0001, 0.00001,
                            1.1, 2.2,
                            2.37, 0, -1.5, -2.5]})
test.max().max()
Out: 2.37000
```

Desirable result:

```
    att1    att2
5   0.5     2.37
```

**UPD:**
I updated the test dataframe as it caused confusions (my fault!). I need to print one row which contains the max value for the whole dataframe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using `idxmax` here after `stack`

```
test.iloc[[test.stack().idxmax()[0]]]
Out[154]: 
   att1  att2
5   2.3  2.37
```

Comment: why do you use `stack`? I thought just passing returns series from `idxmax` to `iloc` and pick `1st` row would be better than utilize stack:   `test.iloc[test.idxmax()].head(1)`

Comment: @andy you are assuming both max for each columns show in the same row .

Comment: yes, base on his data. Otherwise, `test.iloc[test.idxmax()]` would be enough to show both rows. It seems he wants to show rows where `att1` and `att2` is max. So, if att1_max is on different row to att2_max, showing both rows make sense. If he just need to know att1_max and att2_max, then `test.agg(['max'])` is better

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
After OP further explanation, I think comparing `values` array to `values.max()` is more flexible as follows:

```
test[test.values == test.values.max()]
```

It returns the row of max_value of dataframe. In case of att1_max is same as att2_max but on different rows, it returns both rows. In this case, if single row is preferable, add `head(1)` to it.

att1_max and att2_max on same row:

```
Out[660]:
     att1     att2
0  0.1000  0.01000
1  0.0010  0.00010
2  0.0001  0.00001
3  1.0000  1.10000
4  2.0000  2.20000
5  2.3000  2.37000
6  0.0000  0.00000
7 -1.0000 -1.50000
8 -2.0000 -2.50000

In [661]: test[test.values == test.values.max()]
Out[661]:
   att1  att2
5   2.3  2.37
```

att1_max and att2_max on different rows:

```
Out[664]:
     att1     att2
0  0.1000  0.01000
1  0.0010  0.00010
2  0.0001  0.00001
3  1.0000  1.10000
4  2.0000  2.20000
5  2.3000  1.37000
6  0.0000  0.00000
7 -1.0000 -1.50000
8 -2.0000 -2.50000

In [665]: test[test.values == test.values.max()]
Out[665]:
   att1  att2
5   2.3  1.37
```

att1_max is same as att2_max but on different rows(this case `stack` only returns 1 row while this returns both rows)

```
Out[668]:
      att1      att2
0   0.1000   0.01000
1  25.0500   0.00010
2   0.0001   0.00001
3   1.0000   1.10000
4   2.0000   2.20000
5   2.3000   1.37000
6   0.0000   0.00000
7  -1.0000  25.05000
8  -2.0000  -2.50000

In [669]: test[test.values == test.values.max()]
Out[669]:
    att1     att2
1  25.05   0.0001
7  -1.00  25.0500
```

Note: in the last case, if returning single is required, just add `head(1)`

```
In [670]: test[test.values == test.values.max()].head(1)
Out[670]:
    att1    att2
1  25.05  0.0001
```

*Note 2: if att1_max and att2_max is the same and on same row, that row will show twice. In that case using `drop_duplicates()` to handle it*.

**Original:**

@Wen-Ben answer is good, but I think using `stack` here is unneccessary. I prefer `idxmax` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
test.iloc[test.idxmax()].drop_duplicates()
```

or

```
test.loc[test.idxmax().drop_duplicates()]
```

att1_max and att2_max on same row:

```
In [510]: test.iloc[test.idxmax()].drop_duplicates()
Out[510]:
   att1  att2
5   2.3  2.37
```

att1_max and att2_max on different rows:

```
In [513]: test.iloc[test.idxmax()].drop_duplicates()
Out[513]:
   att1  att2
5   2.3  1.37
4   2.0  2.20
```

So, att1_max and att2_max are on same row, return exact 1 row. att1_max and att2_max are on different rows, return 2 rows where att1_max and att2_max exists.

Comment: Hi! I need to print only the row which contains the max value for the whole dataframe. So the result in the second example should be just the row with index 5.

Comment: ah, I see. In case of att1_max is same value as att2_max but they are on different rows, you want to show both rows or either row?

Comment: @aviss Ummm I think that is why I am using stack .

Answer (score 0):

Let's use np.where which returns row and column index:

```
r, _ = np.where(test.values == np.max(test.values))
test.iloc[r]
```

Output:

```
   att1  att2
5   2.3  2.37
```